# Python redis rpop is resultng b'value' list structure

Tags: python, list, redis, docker-compose

I am working on a simple redis and flask project using docker compose. my flask manuplates redis list structure using lpush, rpop. It worked fine until i was playing with commands like brpop which now made all my results b'value'. I tried to work with the first commands only, but somehow the b'value' output keeps coming. Any idea on what might causing this?

```
**redis.lpush('moviestore','likemov')

itle = redis.rpop('moviestore')**
```

Comment: If your are under Python 2, it's normal because you pushed bytes string values. Prefix your string with u if you want Unicode strings, i.e.: u"moviestore".

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Thanks for the tip. I changed my project to python 2 then everything was good like it was before. But, still what do i have to do in python three to get my values without the b' '.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that redis strings are Python bytes strings (see the documentation about [Data Types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)).

So, I think there is a automatic conversion from Unicode to Bytes in Python 3 (and maybe in Python 2 too).

To work with Unicode string, you can encode/decode sting (using UTF8 encoding for instance):

```
redis.lpush('moviestore', u'likemov'.encode('utf8'))
...
itle = redis.rpop('moviestore').decode('utf8')
```

In summary:

- to store Unicode string in Redis: you encode it,
- to retrieve Unicode string from Redis: you decode it.

Notice the differences:

- by default, 'value' is a `str` which is a Bytes string in Python 2 and an Unicode string in Python 3.
- u'value' is an Unicode string: py2 `unicode` / py3 `str`;
- b'value' is a Bytes string: py2 `str` / py3 `bytes`.